# Convergence of entire function, proof check

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I have an exercise that says:

**Let $f$ be an entire function and $\sup_{|z|=r}\left(\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)\rightarrow c \in [0,\infty)$ for $r\rightarrow \infty$. What can you say about $f$ and $c$.**

Due to the unspecific nature of the question, I'm not entirely sure which conclusion I should arrive at. If anyone could check my solution and tell me if I missed something, I would be very grateful.

My argumentation is as follows:

If we look at $f^{n}(0)$ we have that:
\begin{align*}
    |f^{n}(0)| &= \left|\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial K(0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz\right|\\
    &\leq \left|\frac{n! 2 \pi r}{2\pi i}\sup_{|z|=r}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{n+1}}\right| \qquad \text{estimation lemma}\\
    &= n!\sup_{|z|=r}\frac{|f(z)|}{|r|^{n}}\\
    &= n!\sup_{|z|=r}\frac{|f(z)|}{|r|^{n-\frac{3}{2}}|r|^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
    &=\frac{n!}{|r|^{n-\frac{3}{2}}} \sup_{|z|=r}\frac{|f(z)|}{|r|^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
\end{align*}
If we look at what happends when $r\rightarrow \infty$ for different values of $n$, we can see that:
\begin{align*}
    |f^{n}(0)| \leq \begin{cases}
                0 & \text{for } n\geq 2\\
                \infty & \text{for } n \leq 1
                \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is entire, we have that $f'(0)<\infty$. Thus the Taylor series of $f$  with centre 0 will be $f(z)=f(0) + f'(0) z$. In other words $f$ will be a first degree polynomial. Now we have that $|z|^{\frac{3}{2}}\in O(|z|^{\frac{3}{2}})$ and $|f|\in O(|z|)$, but $|z|^{\frac{3}{2}} \not \in O(|z|)$. Therefore $\sup_{|z|=r}\left(\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)\rightarrow 0$ for $r\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Seems correct. In general if a holomorphic function behaves somewhat polynomial it's likely a polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good thing to keep in mind.